# If $n=x^k+y^k$ then also $n=a^2+b^2=c^3+d^3=\ldots =x^k+y^k$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there infinitely many positive integers with the property:
If $n$ is a sum of two $k$th powers then it is also the sum of two $k-1$th powers, the sum of two $k-2$th powers, ... , the sum of two squares?
For example let $n=2^5+1^5=31$. It is the sum of two 5th powers but not the sum of two squares. I am not sure if this has been studied before.
Here we suppose that $k\ge 3$.

**EDIT:** I will give an example mentioned in a comment by Aaron Meyerowitz:
Since $2^{25}$ is a sum of two 24th powers it is required that it is a sum of two 23rd powers, of two 22nd powers etc.
We may be able to find a number $n$ which is of the form $n=a^2+b^2=c^3+d^3=x^4+y^4$ and this seems ok. But it is possible that also $n=k^{12}+l^{12}$ for some $k,l>0$, so we must check if this number is also the sum of two 11th powers, two 10th powers etc.If not, it does not "pass the test".

Comment: Take powers of 2.

Comment: Now it is not clear what you are asking for: if $2^{k!+1}$ is a sum of two $k$th powers...

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you asking whether there are infinitely many $n$ such that there exists $k$ such that $n$ is a sum of two $r$th powers for all $r$, $2\le r\le k$? Or are you asking whether there are infinitely many $k$ for which there exists $n$ such that etc. etc.? Or is it something else?

Comment: The question is clear. Are there infinitely many  n is the question. I am not sure if there is a single number satisfying the conditions above, the "infinitely" avoids any trivial examples. The question IS clear.

Comment: Let $N \geq 2$. A simple counting argument shows that the number of positive integers $n \leq N$ such that $n = x^k + y^k$ for some integers $k \geq 3$ and $x,y \geq 0$ is at most $\frac{\log N}{\log 2}(N^{\frac{1}{3}}+1)^2+2$, since we must have $k \leq \frac{\log N}{\log 2}$ unless $n \leq 2$, which is covered by adding $2$. This bound is $o(N)$. So the answer to your question is "yes", since there are infinitely many positive integers that aren't the sum of two $k$-th powers for any $k \geq 3$. Or do you want to exclude such examples?

Comment: @Gabriel Dill we assume that k is greater than 2. So, you show that there are infinitely many n such that they are the sum of two third powers, of two squares but not the sum of two other powers? This will answer the question if I understand correctly the meaning of the comment.

Comment: No, what I show is that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ that aren't the sum of two $k$-th powers of (non-negative) integers for any $k \geq 3$. One can extend this to show that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ that aren't the sum of two $k$-th powers of non-negative integers for any $k \geq 2$, since the number of $n \leq N$ that are sums of two squares is also $o(N)$.

Comment: @Gabriel Dill but I want to check the case where n is the sum of two powers (third or greater powers).I assume this.

Comment: The order of quantifiers is still unclear. Can you please ensure that you ask a mathematically precise question?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas, your current formulation is of the form "Are there infinitely many positive integers with the property: if P then Q?" Since "if P then Q" is true whenever P is false, the answer to your question is trivially "yes" if there exist infinitely many positive integers such that P is false. And that is the case here, since P is the statement "$n$ is a sum of two $k$th powers". Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 7):

There are infinitely many for $k=3$ and almost surely for $k=4.$ I won't predict $k \geq 5.$ I'd guess that the expected number is infinite but don't expect there to be a construction.

For a positive integer $n$ define the **full profile** to be the set of all $j$ so that there are positive integers $a,b$ with $n=a^j+b^j.$ If $j_1j_2$ is in the profile of $n$ so are $j_1$ and $j_2$. So define the **brief profile** to be those $j$ in the profile so that no multiple of $j$ is.

The question as asked is not explicit about non-negative vs. positive. I don't think it matters. taking that into account, the exact question is

> For each fixed $k \geq 3$ consider the set $S_k$ of integers $n$ with full profile $\{1,2,3,\cdots,k\}$
>
> Q: for which $k$, if any, is $S_k$ infinite?

The number of integers $n \leq x$ with $j$ in their full profile is less than $x^{\frac2j}.$ Assuming things are random , which they definitely are not, and reasoning extremely loosely, that might suggest that any particular full profile occurs infinitely often. I'll only consider what I can construct.

If $n$ has a particular profile then $t^Gn$ likely has the same profile for an integer $t\gt 1$ and $G$ a common multiple of all the integers in the profile. Certainly the profile of $t^Gn$ includes the profile of $n$ and for any other numbers to be in the profile would seem rare. I will call a number with a particular profile **primitive** if it can not be obtained in this fashion from a smaller one. So a single primitive example seems to imply that infinitely many non-primitive examples.

Here is a hueristic argument that $S_3$ should have infinitely many primitive members: (See @Asymptotiac K's answer for a proof) : Let $m$ be an integer which is a sum of two squares, for example a prime of the form $m=4q+1.$ Then $n=m^3+m^3$ is both a sum of two cubes and a sum of two squares. But it seems rare that a particular such $n$ is the sum of two $j$th powers for any $j \gt 3.$

---

Here is an argument that, for odd $j$, there are infinitely many integers primitive with respect to having brief profile $\{j,j+1\}.$  That in turn would say that there are infinitely many primitive members of $S_4.$ The examples have the added property that each is a sum of two *equal* $j+1$th powers.

Let $a$ and $b$ be odd with $m=\frac{a^j+b^j}4$ be an integer. For example require  $a \bmod j=1$ and $b \bmod j=-1.$  Then $$n=(2ma)^j+(2mb)^j=2^jm^j(a^j+b^j)=2^{j+2}m^{j+1}=(2m)^{j+1}+(2m)^{j+1}.$$

It is not impossible that such an $n$ would be a sum of two even larger powers , but this would be quite rare. Perhaps one could prove this does not happen for an infinite class of cases. I'll suffice to report that for $j=3$ with $a=4q-1 \lt 400$ and $b=1,$ the one failure is for $s=6,m=23^3+1=2\cdot78^2.$ Then $n=2^5m^4=2^978^8$ is the sum of two equal $8$th powers, but not $7$th powers.

The smallest number in $S_4$ is $18737=24^3+17^3=8^4+11^4.$

The next smallest thing fits the pattern above:
$3^3+1^3=2^27$ so $n=(2\cdot 3\cdot 7)^3+(2\cdot 1 \cdot  7)^3=2^57^4$ is a sum of two cubes but also a sum of two $4$th powers (and hence of two squares): $(2\cdot 7)^4+(2\cdot 7)^4=2^57^4.$

That particular technique could be modified to strongly suggest that for any relatively prime $j \lt k$ there are infinitely many integers primitive with respect to having brief profile $\J,k\}.$

---

All these examples have $n=c^3+d^3=e^4+f^4$ with $c,d,e,f$ sharing a large common factor. It might be interesting to try to find examples where, say, one or both pairs $c,d$ and $e,f$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Sorry, but why can't the set $S_k$ be finite? I don't really see why $n\in S_k$ implies $t^{[1,2,\ldots,k]}n\in S_k$ for any $t$...

Comment: Maybe not every $t$ but probably infinitely many $t.$ I am suggesting that if $n\in S_k$, so $n$ is **not** a sum of two $j$th powers for any $j \gt k,$ then it is safe to assume that neither is $t^{k!}n$  ( for infinitely many, if not almost all, prime $t$... just to be safe.) But  $t^{k!}n$ is a sum of two $j$th powers for every $j \leq k$ since $n$ is.

Answer (score 5):

To make Aaron's argument a bit more formal:
Let $p$ be some prime number of the form $16m+5$ and $n=2p^3$. For $k=1,2,3$ there exist pairs $(a_k,b_k)$ with $a_k^k+b_k^k=n$ (take $a_1=b_1=p^3$, $a_3=b_3=p$ and $a_2=(a+b)(a^2+b^2), b_2=(a-b)(a^2+b^2)$, where $a>b>0$ are integers with $a^2+b^2=p$)

I claim that for any $k>3$ there is no solution for

$$x^k+y^k=n$$

with $x,y\in \mathbb N$.

Proof:

Assume that $k$ is not a power of $2$. Then there exist some odd $q\geq 3$ with $q \mid k$. Therefore if

$$x^k+y^k=n,$$

then $$x^{k/q}+y^{k/q}\mid x^k+y^k.$$ But $x$ and $y$ should both be odd, so $x^{k/q}+y^{k/q}$ is even. But for any natural number $q>1$ we have

$$A^q+B^q\geq 2^{1-q}(A+B)^q$$

if $A,B>0$. Equality is attained only if $A=B$. Now, we have

$$z=x^{k/q}+y^{k/q}=2p^\ell\geq 2p,$$

since it is even and divides $2p^3$ (and also $xy\neq 1$). Therefore we have

$n=2p^3=(x^{k/q})^q+(y^{k/q})^q\geq 2^{1-q}z^q\geq 2p^q$. Therefore, we should have either $q=3$ and $x=y=p^{3/k}$, which is not the case as $k>3$ or $k=2^m$ with some $m\geq 2$. In this last case we have

$$x^{2^m}\equiv y^{2^m}\equiv 1 \pmod {16},$$

because $x$ and $y$ are odd and $2^m$ is divisible by $4$. Therefore

$$10\equiv 2\cdot 5^3\equiv 2p^3=x^k+y^k\equiv 2 \pmod {16},$$

which is a contradiction.

Comment: You never use that $p$ is prime so this should be valid for any $n=16m+5$ with all (odd) prime-divisors (of the square-free part) equal to $1 \bmod 4.$ The same is then true for $2n^3$ or even $2^in^3.$

Comment: In fact, I do use the primality of $p$ to prove the lower bound for $x^{k/q}+y^{k/q}$

Comment: Fair enough! Very nice. Of course one could say that the number of such $n$ far exceeds the number which could be a sum of two larger equal powers.

Answer (score 3):

It is true for $n=2^{k!+1}$ and $a=b=2^{k!/2}$, $c=d=2^{k!/3}$,...

Comment: Ok this is true but it is not what I wanted to ask. I will edit the question.

Comment: Check the edited question, sorry for the misunderstanding I caused.

Comment: Alexey's reponse still answers your question. He gave infinitely many $n$'s such that $n$ is a sum of $k$-th powers and also a sum of $(k-1)$-th powers etc. So the "if" clause is true and the "then" clause is also true, whence the "if ... then ..." implication is also true. If this is not clear, then I suggest you review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table

Comment: $2^{4!+1}=8^8+8^8$, but equation $2^{4!+1}=x^7+y^7$ has no integer solutions. If we don't assume that $k$ is fixed (i.e. "FOR ANY $k$, if $n=a^k+b^k$, then etc.), then $n=2^{4!+1}$ is not an example.

Comment: @GH from MO this answer is obviously false.Asymptotiac explains why

Comment: Also $2^{a!+1}=2^{a!}+2^{a!}$ is a sum of two $j$th powers for $j=a!$ but not for $j=a!-1.$

Comment: @Asymptotiac K and Aaron Meyerowitz: Alexey Ustinov is right. For exmample he claims: 2^{4!+1} = a^4+a^4= c^3 +c^3 = e^2+e^2 =g+g$. Read his post

Comment: The question is: since $n=2^{25}$ is also a sum of two $k$th powers for $k=24$ it is also required to be a sum of two $23$rd powers?

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: I think that was not the question. The question was if there are infinitely many $n$'s such that *if* $n$ is the sum of two $k$-th powers, *then* it is also the sum of two $(k-1)$-th power etc. The above answer shows that there are infinitely many $n$'s for which the "if clause" and the "then clause" simultaneously hold, i.e. the "if ... then ..." statement also holds. Perhaps the OP had something different in mind, but the way his question stands now, it is answered above.

Comment: Your interpretation might be correct, but then the word "if" looks weird. If the question is "Given $k$ are there infinitely many integers which are a sum of two $j$th powers for every $j \leq k?$" The answer is "sure, take $n=u^{k!}+v^{k!}.$" If you are going to brandish the definition of "if-then" you must admit that any $n$ which is **not** a sum of two $k$th powers  automatically makes the preposition true.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: The whole question looks weird, it is not clearly stated. And yes, I agree with your last sentence! Your variant (in your response) is interesting BTW.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz this is EXACTLY the question.

Answer (score 2):

Above equation shown below:

$n=a^2+b^2=c^3+d^3=d^4+e^4=f^5+g^5$

In the above chain Seiji Tomita has given parametric solution to the equality:

$n=d^4+e^4=f^5+g^5$

Numerical solution is:

$(97245522,291736566)^4=(5893668,2946834)^5$

Refer to article #265 on Seiji Tomita's web site given below & click on "Computational number theory":

```
   http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/eindex.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Equation shown above is shown below:

$n=a^2+b^2=c^3+d^3=x^4+y^4$

Above equation has numerical solution:

$n=(881)^5(30835)^4=(21902832315343448,246035858286911)^2
                    =(71798773305,47865848870)^3=(135828175,108662540)^4$

Comment: But the question is whether that $n$ can also be written as a sum of, say, two seventh powers.

Answer (score 0):

$n=a^2+b^2=c^3+d^3=e^6+f^6=g^7+h^7$

Above equation has numerical solution but 'n' takes on 
some  $n=10^{65}$ digit's. (Regarding the query by Gerry Myerson)

$n=(2188)^{29}
*(142220)^7$

$a=2236177983622751751940458062567870996588928245958351378266837745664$

$b=1884697278777914945692455733067301781628362257696006701413304369152$

$c=50862127851435727075668189478739919870361600$

$d=20344851140574290830267275757914959679481446400$

$e=14263537829225360465920$

$f=7131768914612680232960$

$g=9778476573966197760$

$h=3259492191322065920$

Comment: I think you are missing the point of my comment (and of the original question). OP wants numbers $n$ and $k\ge3$ such that $n$ is a sum of two $r$th powers for every $r$ up to $k$ but for no $r$ beyond $k$.